# three.js r141 planegeometry's vertices is undefined

Tags: three.js

I am trying to update the vertices, but it's `.vertices` being undefined.

```
  const geometry = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(1.7, 1, 15, 9)
  // or new THREE.PlaneGeometry(1.7, 1, 15, 9)

  const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: color})
  const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material)

  mesh.geometry.vertices.map(v => {
     // being defined 
     console.log(v)

     v.z = .6 * Math.sin(v.x * 2 + this.elapsedTime)
  })
```

so I checked the `mesh.geometry.vertices`, but there is no property of that name. is newer patches (r141) changes the way handling vertex update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PlaneBufferGeometry` and `PlaneGeometry` always created an instance of `BufferGeometry` since `r125`.

Instances of `BufferGeometry` do not have a `vertices` property. If you want to access vertex data, you have to work with the `position` buffer attribute. Your code has to look like so:

```js
const positionAttribute = geometry.getAttribute( 'position' );

for ( let i = 0; i < positionAttribute.count; i ++ ) {

    const x = positionAttribute.getX( i );
    const value = 0.6 * Math.sin( x * 2 + this.elapsedTime );
    positionAttribute.setZ( i, value );

}
positionAttribute.needsUpdate = true;
```

More information here: https://discourse.threejs.org/t/three-geometry-will-be-removed-from-core-with-r125/22401